# How to remove 'enters' from TSQL scripts executed in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, sql-server-2008

I'm working with a lot of TSQL scripts that perform management tasks on the SQL Server. Those scripts are saved as .sql files and executed by a DBA in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I use the `print` statement to echo some information back to the DBA.

Consider the following simplification of a script:

```
PRINT 'Update user...'
UPDATE [User] SET UserName = UserName WHERE UserName = 'Administrator' 

PRINT 'Delete user...'
DELETE FROM [User] WHERE UserName = 'Nothing' 

PRINT 'Update & Delete finished'
```

When I'm running this script I get the following output:

```
Update user...

(1 row(s) affected)
Delete user...

(0 row(s) affected)
Update & Delete finished
```

There is always an **enter** before the result of the query. Some of my DBA's are complaining about the readability of the output. It is especially hard to interpret the results when a cursor is used in a script.

**Is there a way to get rid of the preceding enters when the result of an action is displayed?**

Comment: I think if your DBAs are any good and this is so important to them, then they should be able to figure this out...

Comment: True. But as they haven't, I decided to put the question on SO :-).

Comment: Would printing a line before each of your messages aid readability at all?

Comment: No... the best would be something like 'Update user...' [newline] (1 row(s) affected) [newline][newline] {next message} '

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `SET NOCOUNT ON` , get the rows affected via `@@ROWCOUNT` and print a custom message yourself.

Comment: Yeah... it gets rid of the enters. Is there a more out-of-the box way to influence the enters?

Comment: @Kees - Not AFAIK. I've never seen such an option in SSMS. Plus I presume they would really prefer summary information to individual rowcount messages anyway.